# Can I make a special file in linux that is actually the output of a script?

Tags: text-processing

Can I make a special file in linux, perhaps using mknod, that is actually the output of a script?

example:

`cat specialfile`

output:

`testing 123`

inside specialfile:

`echo "testing 123"`

So instead of actually showing  `echo "testing 123"`
it shows the result of the script output `testing 123`

I realize the script name and the output handle may have to be two different files so it can be edited
ie.  `specialfile.sh` for the script and  `specialfile` for the handle

Comment: mknod creates a device node, and there must be something on the other end of that device node. You may want to look at sockets, which are files which have a process sitting on the other side reacting to I/O requests (they are commonly used for inter-process communication, for example).

Comment: Can you move the file pointer around in a socket, though?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a named FIFO (`mkfifo <name>`), and then do:

```
mkfifo my-fifo
echo "testing 123" > my-fifo
```

And in another shell do:

```
dumb-program my-fifo
```

To the dumb program, the FIFO looks like a file (not completely, since it won't be seekable). That's equivalent to doing it with anonymous pipes like this:

```
echo "testing 123" | dumb-program /dev/stdin
```

Or using process substitution in modern shells like this:

```
dumb-program <(echo "testing 123")
```

I'm not sure about device nodes, but to me it seems that you're approaching the problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the `cat` in a subshell on the command-line:

```
$(cat specialfile)
```

The output will then be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not good enough as the file is read by a "dumb" program and I need the output to be dynamic instead.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.